# How to define a function that returns a function with signature dependent on parameters

Tags: f#

I'd like to get F# code that leads to same behavior as following C# code:

```
public abstract class ModelBase<TIn, TOut>
{
  internal abstract Func<TIn, TOut> GetFuncInternal();
}

public class Model1 : ModelBase<Tuple<int, int>, int>
{
  private int _val;
  public Model1(int val)
  {
    _val = val;
  }

  internal override Func<Tuple<int, int>, int> GetFuncInternal()
  {
    return _ => _val; 
  }
}

public class Model2 : ModelBase<Tuple<int, double>, double>
{
  private double _val;
  public Model2(double val)
  {
    _val = val;
  }

  internal override Func<Tuple<int, double>, double> GetFuncInternal()
  {
    return _ => _val;
  }
}

public class Model3 : ModelBase<int, bool>
{
  internal override Func<int, bool> GetFuncInternal()
  {
    return _ => true;
  }
}

public static class Helpers
{
  public static Func<TIn, TOut> GetFunc<TIn, TOut>(ModelBase<TIn, TOut> model)
  {
    return model.GetFuncInternal();
  }
}
```

So code above can be used in the following way:

```
var func1 = Helpers.GetFunc(new Model1(1));
var func2 = Helpers.GetFunc(new Model2(1.0));
var func3 = Helpers.GetFunc(new Model3());
```

As you can see the type of `GetFunc` result depends on type of its parameters.

In F# Models defined as discriminated union:

```
type Model = 
  | Model1 of int
  | Model2 of double
  | Model3
```

And the question is: how to define `GetFunc` in F#? I need something like that (of course following sample doesn't compiled because of type mismatch in pattern matching):

```
let GetFunc (m: Model) = 
  match  m with
  | Model1 i -> fun (x: int, y: int) -> i
  | Model2 d -> fun (x: int, y: double) -> d
  | Model3 ->   fun (x: int) -> true
```

Comment: When you run your C# code, it doesn't do anything (it creates some delegates, but they're never used), so you can replace it with empty F# program :-). If you can provide some context of what are you trying to do, then you'll get more useful answer..

Answer (score 2):

Don't define `Model` like that.  Actually, it's hard to tell what you're doing, but this smells like a domain where you don't need to define any types.  Just use lambdas and you don't need any of these model types.  What are you actually trying to do?